# shap plots for random forest models

Tags: r, random-forest, shap

I would like to get the Shap Contribution for variables for a Ranger/random forest model and have plots like this in R:

[beeswarm plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPDVp.png)

I have tried using the following libraries: DALEX, shapr, fastshap, shapper. I could only end up getting plots like this:
[fastshap plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieD1g.png)

Is it possible to get such plots? I have tried reticulate package and it still doesnt work.

Comment: This post looks promising: https://www.r-statistics.com/2011/03/beeswarm-boxplot-and-plotting-it-with-r/

Answer (score 3):

Random forests need to grow many **deep** trees. While possible, crunching TreeSHAP for **deep** trees requires an awful lot of memory and CPU power. An alternative is to use the Kernel SHAP algorithm, which works for all kind of models.

```r
library(ranger)
library(kernelshap)
library(shapviz)

set.seed(1)
fit <- ranger(Sepal.Length ~ ., data = iris,)

# Step 1: Calculate Kernel SHAP values
# bg_X is usually a small (50-200 rows) subset of the data
s <- kernelshap(fit, iris[-1], bg_X = iris)

# Step 2: Turn them into a shapviz object
sv <- shapviz(s)

# Step 3: Gain insights...
sv_importance(sv, kind = "bee")
sv_dependence(sv, v = "Petal.Length", color_var = "auto")
```

[image: SHAP summary plot]
[image: SHAP dependence plot]

Disclaimer: I wrote "kernelshap" and "shapviz"

Comment: why iris[-1] ? you removed Sepal.Length. Did you intend to remove species instead?

Comment: Excluding the response ("Sepal.Length") from the data seems correct. Just very recently, {treeshap} has arrived on CRAN. You can do the crunching with it and then use {shapviz} for the plots.

Comment: I tried to use it but I got NA values in my results. I figured out that treeshap cannot deal with factor values while my response variable is.

Comment: Can't you simply turn into an integer and set `probability = TRUE`?

Comment: I've tried but it's better to put classification = TRUE otherwise I will run through some error ("> rf= ranger.unify(fit, train_data)
Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent") when trying to unify the model in order to compute the shap values with the treeshap package.

Comment: Good to know, thx!

Comment: Hey Michael, I tried to use different subsets of my data and it gives varying results. However, at the same time trying to use my entire dataframe (~7000obs.) seems impossible for kernelshap to function. I waited 30min and couldn't see a percentage of improvement. So... how reliable are the results when using only a small subset of the data ?

Comment: I usually pick 1000 rows to explain (`X`) and 100-500 rows as background data (`bg_X`). Random forest predictions are very expensive, so you can even reduce the sizes a little bit. I don't think you will miss something important in this way. The status bar should be perfectly linear in the size of `X`, while the size of the background data blows up memory and crunching time per observation.

Comment: Hmm I see. In my case, I have an unbalanced dataset. Especially for observations between the different categories of my Y variable. So, setting 1000 rows would not be a good idea.

Comment: @MichaelM can you kindly check my question on this, I tried using your code in my case and it didn't seem to function.
Take a look please...