# shap plots of multivariate random forest model with randomforestSRC package in R

Tags: random-forest, shap

I am trying to figure out a way to plot the shap values of a multivariate random forest model with multiple correlated outcome variables in R.

In order to predict a multivariate random forest model, I am using the rfsrc function of the R package randomforestSRC.

Here an example where the two outcome variables mpg and wt are predicted.

```
library(randomForestSRC)

mod1 <- rfsrc(Multivar(mpg, wt )~., data = mtcars, importance=T)

randomForestSRC::print.rfsrc(mod1, outcome.target = "mpg")
randomForestSRC::print.rfsrc(mod1, outcome.target = "wt")
```

Is there a way to plot the shap values of the above model?

Or is there another R package that allows predicting multivariate random forest models with multiple correlated outcome variables, that then allows plotting the shap values?

Thanks in advance to anyone who will help!

PS: I found great instructions on how to plot the shap values of random forest model with a single outcome variable (see for instance [shap plots for random forest models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65391767/shap-plots-for-random-forest-models)). These instructions are based on random forest R packages that, to the best of my knowledge, do not allow to run models with multiple outcome variables.

Answer (score 1):

(My) {kernelshap} and {shapviz} can deal with multioutput models, but finding the predictions in the result of `rfsrc::predict()` is not that easy...

```r
library(randomForestSRC)
library(kernelshap)
library(shapviz)

mod1 <- rfsrc(Multivar(mpg, wt ) ~ ., data = mtcars, importance = TRUE)
x <- c("cyl", "disp", "hp", "drat", "qsec", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb")
pred_fun <- function(m, x) {
  pred <- predict(m, newdata=x)$regrOutput
  sapply(pred, `[[`, "predicted")
}
pred_fun(mod1, head(mtcars))

shap_values <- kernelshap(
  mod1, 
  X = mtcars[x], 
  bg_X = mtcars,  # Usually small random sample
  pred_fun = pred_fun
)
sv <- shapviz(shap_values)
names(sv) <- c("mpg", "wt")  # Not yet automatically
sv_importance(sv)
sv_dependence(sv, "cyl")
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Also keep an eye on the treeshap package of my colleagues. In the future, it will also be able to deal with randomforestscr