# SHAP for xgboost issue for multiclass classification: "error in colnames"

Tags: r, xgboost, shap

I am trying to compute the SHAP Values of my xgboost model:

```
X_train <- as.matrix(train_data[, !names(train_data) %in% c("min_column")])
Y_train<-train_data$min_column
Y_train <- as.integer(as.factor(Y_train)) - 1
Y_train = as.matrix(Y_train)
num_class <- length(unique(Y_train)

> params <- list(booster = "gbtree", 
                 objective = "multi:softmax",
                 eta=0.01, 
                 gamma=0.01, 
                 max_depth=2, 
                 subsample=1, 
                 num_class=num_class)

> xgb1 <- xgb.train(data = X_train, label = Y_train, verbose = FALSE, params = params, nrounds = 10)


> shap_values <- SHAPforxgboost::shap.values(xgb_model = xgb1, X_train = X_train)
```

however, I always get the following error:

```
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c(colnames(X_train), "BIAS")) : 
      attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions
```

I figured out that when I don't specify in the parameters list the parameters related to a multiclass classification model `(booster = "gbtree" + objective = "multi:softmax"+ num_class)`, the shap.values function does work.

But if I don't specify it in the parameters, I am not sure whether the model will recognize that I want a multiclass classification model.

Is there someone who knows what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{SHAPforxgboost} does not support multi-output models. This is one of the reasons why we made {shapviz}:

```r
library(xgboost)
library(shapviz)

params <- list(objective = "multi:softprob", num_class = 3, learning_rate = 0.2)
X_pred <- data.matrix(iris[, -5])
dtrain <- xgboost::xgb.DMatrix(X_pred, label = as.integer(iris[, 5]) - 1)
fit <- xgboost::xgb.train(
  params = params, 
  data = dtrain, 
  nrounds = 100
)

shap_values <- shapviz(fit, X_pred = X_pred)
names(shap_values) <- levels(iris$Species)

# Analyze one class
sv_importance(shap_values$versicolor, kind = "bee")
sv_dependence(shap_values$versicolor, v = colnames(iris[, -5]))
```

[image]
[image]

```r
# Or all together
sv_importance(shap_values, kind = "bee", alpha = 0.2)
sv_dependence(shap_values, v = "Sepal.Width")
```

[image]
[image]

SHAP interactions work as well:

```r
shap_inter <- shapviz(fit, X_pred = X_pred, interactions = TRUE)
names(shap_inter) <- levels(iris$Species)

sv_interaction(shap_inter$versicolor, kind = "bee")
sv_dependence(
  shap_inter$versicolor, 
  v = "Sepal.Width",
  color_var = colnames(iris[, -5]),
  interactions = TRUE
)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Michael!! Just to seek some clarification: when you state 'For XGBoost, LightGBM, and H2O, the SHAP values are directly calculated from the fitted model,' do you mean that the shapviz function computes the SHAP values itself, or that it can retrieve them from the XGBoost model directly?

Comment: Directly from XGBoost's TreeSHAP implementation. Scott Lundberg's hard work :-). shapviz and shap4xgboost only visualize the results.

Comment: Thanks! maybe one last need of clarification: why don't I get a general mean shap plot instead of a separate shap plot for each level of my categorical variable ?

Comment: Do you mean the bar plot?

Comment: Yes. Like one bar plot for all the levels of my Y variable combined.

Comment: I will think about it, maybe as stacked bar plot.

Comment: Hey Michael: looking at the xgboost's package documentation, I figure out that setting predcontribute=TRUE does compute the shap values through the predict function. But here you run the model and directly apply the shapviz function. How are your shap values computed then ?

Comment: Via `predict(..., predcontribute = TRUE)`, certainly!

Comment: thanks. There is something strange though. When I compute the XGB' shap values internally with "xgb.plot.shap(X_pred, model=fit, shap_contrib=NULL, top_n=10)" and plot them with shapviz, I get a bar plot for each categories. However, when I compute the shapvalues though kernelSHAP or treeSHAP for a random forest, I get a stacked one. Do you know why ?

Comment: No idea. There are no stacked barplots in {shapviz}, I *think*.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the Y variable being an integer and setting classification = TRUE as you suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65391767/shap-plots-for-random-forest-models/74748182?noredirect=1#comment136192913_74748182